# Attempting to upgrade from Rails 4.0.4 to 4.1.0 gem 'acts_as_commentable_with_threading' causes error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

trying to upgrade Rails from version 4.0.4 to 4.1.0.  This statement in the comments model causes a runtime error

Comments Model

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection

  # added by me so comments_on_comments sorted appropriately
  default_scope  { order(:updated_at => :desc) }

  # causes error in rails 4.1.0
  acts_as_nested_set :scope => [:commentable_id, :commentable_type]

  validates :body, :presence => true
  validates :user, :presence => true
  ...
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.1.1'
...
gem 'acts_as_commentable_with_threading', '~> 1.2.0'
```

causes this error in the Dev log

```
Unknown key: :order. Valid keys are: :class_name, :class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :table_name, :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove, :extend, :primary_key, :dependent, :as, :through, :source, :source_type, :inverse_of, :counter_cache
acts_as_nested_set :scope => [:commentable_id, :commentable_type] -- is highlighted
```

Commenting out "acts_as_nested_set :scope => [:commentable_id, :commentable_type]" in the Comment model then causes this error when selecting an article (which has comments on the article.

```
undefined method `children' for #<Comment:0x00000107260040>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a known issue with `awesome_nested_set` (a dependency of `acts_as_commentable_with_threading`) and Rails 4.1/ruby 2.1.

https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set/issues/253

Try updating your version of awesome_nested_set to ~> 3.0.0.rc.3 as suggested.

Comment: Many thanks - a privelage of having got some points on Stack Overflow is the ability to accept answers as well as vote up - thanks - Pierre

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to deprecated syntax in `awesome_nested_set`.  I got this error in rSpec when using the `acts_as_commentable_with_threading` gem v.2.1.6:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The following options in your Comment.has_many :children declaration are deprecated: :order. Please use a scope block instead. For example, the following:

    has_many :spam_comments, conditions: { spam: true }, class_name: 'Comment'

should be rewritten as the following:

    has_many :spam_comments, -> { where spam: true }, class_name: 'Comment'
. (called from <class:Comment> at /Users/reconstructions/Desktop/Coding 2013/Rails Apps/sfrc/app/models/comment.rb:2)
```

The line causing this error was the same one described above, and the scope syntax is stale.

Bumping to `gem "awesome_nested_set", '~> 3.0.0.rc.3'` worked for me, so the above answer is correct.  If anyone can't or doesn't want to bump to that versions, fixing this syntax error might be a place to start.